# Bind goals to cascade them like phases in Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Let's say I have 5 different goals linked to Mojos that I want to be able to bind, named from goal-a to goal-e.

I would like to be able to bind them like maven lifecycle phases, i.e. if I define an execution path and I call a goal, all previous goals on this path are executed beforehand.

I would then have :

```
goal-a -> { goal-b -> goal-d
          { goal-c -> goal-e
```

So if I run `mvn groupdId:artifactId:myPlugin:goal-d`, it executes `goal-a`, `goal-b`, `goal-d`.
If i run the same command with `goal-e`, it executes `goal-a`, `goal-c`, `goal-e`.

Is there any way to define such bindings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom plugin quite easily that will accomplish what you are looking for using the [Mojo Executor](http://timmoore.github.io/mojo-executor/).

For instance, you can write a Mojo for goal-d and in it, you can use the Mojo Executor to execute the goal-a and goal-b Mojos.

Comment: Is this sable, well maintained, and usable in an enterprise context ?

Comment: @Claw: The project's [github](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor), you can check out the project's releases, contributors, and pace to determine whether it is maintained sufficiently for your needs.  Source and Documentation can be downloaded from their site as well.  It is licensed under Apache 2.0.  As far as the Maven Plugin concept: it is as easy to use in the Enterprise context as traditional maven artifacts.  I believe every Maven developer should  author at least one, if only to understand the flexibility that it allows you to leverage.

Answer (score 0):

You can add execution of your plugin into `<build>` block or create separate profile for its run, and there define all goals. Here is an example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>    
        <plugin>
           <groupId>your.plugin.group.id</groupId>
           <artifactId>your-plugin-artifact-id</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                  <!-- here you need to specify build phase where your plugin execution will be started -->
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <!-- here you can add all your goals to execute -->                            
                  <goals>
                      <goal>goal-a</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

When you execute phase `install` on project your plugin will execute its goals.

Comment: Having to rely on maven phases is not very user friendly, because then the goals names are hidden. In my case, goals are "build", "generate-sql" and "load-sql", respectively to build some code, generate an sql query to store the compilation result in a DB, and the last goal is to execute the query to a database.
Since other people will have to use it, I would like to keep it clear with explicit execution commands.

Comment: If it's supposed to launch all this goals together, then why don't you create one (or two) goals, which will call them all step by step?

Comment: Because I also need to be able to launch them individually, and if so, also go though the previous steps.

Comment: Binding the goals to specific lifecycle phases as described is the "Maven Way".  The alternative is to write your own plugin, which may include a custom lifecycle.  The [Sonatype Maven reference book](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html) explains how.